# Displaying cropped part of frame in video: Error (-215) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function cv::imshow

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

Pardon me if this is a redundant question but I referred all the possible solution related to the error above but none helped me enough to resolve my problem.

I am working on this code below to display the cropped part (roi_1) of video (mag, ang) separately in different window but I get the following error for the piece of code where I am trying to display cropped part (roi_1). I would be really glad with any help with issue

Below you will find comments stating the part of code that is throwing this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "D:/Code/Python/franeback.py", line 35, in <module>
    cv2.imshow('ROI', roi_1)
    cv2.error: D:\Build\OpenCV\opencv-3.2.0\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:‌​312: 
        error: (-215) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function cv::imshow
```

---

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

cap =  cv2.VideoCapture('D:\\test2.MP4')
ret, frame1 = cap.read()
prvs = cv2.cvtColor(frame1,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
hsv = np.zeros_like(frame1)
hsv[...,1] = 255

while(1):
    ret, frame2 = cap.read()
    next = cv2.cvtColor(frame2,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    flow = cv2.calcOpticalFlowFarneback(prvs,next, None, 0.5, 3, 15, 3, 5, 1.2, 0)

    mag, ang = cv2.cartToPolar(flow[...,0], flow[...,1])
    hsv[...,0] = ang*180/np.pi/2
    hsv[...,2] = cv2.normalize(mag,None,0,255,cv2.NORM_MINMAX)
    cv2.rectangle(mag, (200, 220), (350, 350), (255, 255, 0), 2)
    cv2.rectangle(mag, (400, 520), (600, 600), (255, 255, 0), 2)
    roi_1= mag[200:220, 350:350]
    cv2.imshow('frame2',mag)
    k = cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xff
    if k == 27:
        break
    cv2.rectangle(ang, (200, 220), (350, 350), (0, 255, 0), 2)
    cv2.rectangle(ang, (400, 520), (600, 600), (0, 255, 0), 2)
    cv2.imshow('frame1', ang)
    r = cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xff
    if r == 27:
        break

# Part throwing error starts
    cv2.imshow('ROI', roi_1)
    s = cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xff
    if s == 27:
        break
#Part throwing error ends

    prvs = next
    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Please, proof-read your post and fix the indentation of your code -- it rather matters in Python. | The error is quite likely due to not checking whether `cap.read()` succeeded or not, and passing an empty image to other functions.

Comment: I did that and I am quite sure its not because of indentation and cap.read().Although thanks for your reply and I will check again

Comment: I don't mean that the problem is caused by indentation, but in the post it is clearly wrong (your while loop has no body), and as such it is not a [mcve].

Comment: Roger that! I made the changes.. Thank you for bringing it to notice.

Comment: Ok, can you also add the full traceback? Which imshow throws the exception? What's the value of the variable you tried to display?

Comment: Here you go : Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Code/Python/franeback.py", line 35, in <module>
    cv2.imshow('ROI', roi_1)
cv2.error: D:\Build\OpenCV\opencv-3.2.0\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:312: error: (-215) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function cv::imshow

Comment: Ah, I see it now. `roi_1= mag[200:220, 350:350]` -- your range for the second index is of length 0.

Comment: I didn't understand what you mean?

Comment: Got it! Got it!! :) Thank you so much @DanMašek

Comment: Ok. If it solves the problem, feel free to write up an answer yourself and accept it ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it!

Focusing on my traceback, you see `error: (-215) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function cv::imshow`

This suggests the problem is in how I create the `roi_1` -- `roi_1= mag[200:220, 350:350]`. The range for the second index is of length 0 (everything >=350 and <350), which it shouldn't be.

I changed it to `roi_1= mag[200:220, 350:370]` and I am not getting the same error anymore.

Comment: Don't forget to select the checkmark on the left hand side to accept this as a valid answer.

Comment: I can select it only after 2 days after I answered it :D